# React, destructuring, update

Tags: reactjs

estoy iniciando mis primeros pasos con react. Estoy programando un crud, pero tengo problemas para editar el registro. Estoy usando react 16.13, axios para la conección, la api esta con net core 3 y la bd en sql server, la base de datos tiene las tablas relacionadas. Estoy usando: useContext, useState, useEffect. El problema es que no esta ejecutando el destructuring: const { titulo, descripcion } = proyecto;

No muestra los datos en el form

Los valores en el context y que se asignan al state son:

```
proyectoActualDatos: [{…}]
0:
{descripcion: "Se lleva a cabo en", idProyecto: 15, idTipoTabla:…}
descripcion: "Se lleva a cabo en"
idProyecto: 15
idTipoTabla: 1
idTipoTablaNavigation: null
idUnidad: 1
idUnidadNavigation: null
tiProyectoUsuario: []
titulo: "Encuesta"
```

Y cuando edito la información

```
State {0: {…}, descripcion: "Mapa tematico 1", titulo: "M…}
0 {descripcion: "Mapa tematico", idProyecto: 17, idTi…}
idProyecto: 17
idUnidad: 1
idTipoTabla: 1
**titulo: "Mapa"
descripcion: "Mapa tematico"**
idTipoTablaNavigation: null
idUnidadNavigation: null
tiProyectoUsuario: []
**titulo: "Mapa 1"
descripcion: "Mapa tematico 1"**
```

Esta duplicando el título y descripción y no lo esta escribiendo sobre el mismo objeto (titulo y descripción se ven dobles).

¿Que esta mal en el destructuring?, ojala me puedan ayudar, de antemano gracias.

El codigo es:

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import proyectoContext from '../../context/proyectos/proyectoContext';

const ProyectoEditar = () => {

   // Extrar si un proyecto esta activo
   const proyectosContext = useContext(proyectoContext);
   const { proyectoActualDatos, agregarProyecto } = proyectosContext;

   // State del formulario
   const [proyecto, guardarProyecto] = useState({
    idProyecto: null,
    idUnidad: null,
    idTipoTabla: null,
    titulo: '',
    descripcion: '',
    idTipoTablaNavigation: null,
    idUnidadNavigation: null      
    })
    //        tiProyectoUsuario: []  

    // Effect que detecta si hay una proyecto seleccionada
    useEffect(() => {
        if(proyectoActualDatos !== null) {
            console.log("effect");
            console.log(proyectoActualDatos);
            console.log(proyectoActualDatos.titulo);
            guardarProyecto(proyectoActualDatos)
        } else {
            guardarProyecto({
                idProyecto: 0,
                idUnidad: 0,
                idTipoTabla: 0,
                titulo: '',
                descripcion: '',
                idTipoTablaNavigation: null,
                idUnidadNavigation: null,
                tiProyectoUsuario: [] 
            })
        }
    }, [ proyectoActualDatos]);    

   // extraer datos del proyecto
    const { titulo, descripcion } = proyecto;
    console.log(titulo);
    // Aqui esta el ERROR, UNDEFINED

     // Leer los valores del formulario
    const handleChange = e => {
        guardarProyecto({
            ...proyecto,
            [e.target.name]: e.target.type === 'number' ? parseInt(e.target.value) : e.target.value
        })
    }

   const onSubmit = e => {
       e.preventDefault();

       // validar


        // Si es edición o si es nuevo proyecto
        if(proyectoActualDatos === null ) {
            modificarProducto(proyecto);
        } else {
           agregarProyecto(proyecto);
        }

       // Obtener y filtrar las tareas del proyecto actual

       // reiniciar el form
   }   


    return ( 

        <div>
                        <form
                            className="formulario-nuevo-proyecto"
                            onSubmit={onSubmit}
                        >
                            <input 
                                type="number"
                                className="input-text"
                                placeholder="Nombre Tarea..."
                                name="idUnidad"

                                onChange={handleChange}
                            />
                            <input 
                                type="number"
                                className="input-text"
                                placeholder="Nombre Tarea..."
                                name="idTipoTabla"

                                onChange={handleChange}
                            />                                                        
                            <input 
                                type="text"
                                className="input-text"
                                placeholder="Nombre Tarea..."
                                name="titulo"
                                value={titulo}
                                onChange={handleChange}
                            />
                            <label value="Descripcion"></label>
                            <input 
                                type="text"
                                className="input-text"
                                placeholder="Descripción"
                                name="descripcion"

                                onChange={handleChange}
                            />                            

                            <input 
                                type="submit"
                                className="btn btn-primary btn-block"
                                value="Editar Proyecto"
                            />

                        </form>


        </div>

     );
}

export default ProyectoEditar;
```

Comment: puedes probar con const { titulo, descripcion } = props.proyecto;

Comment: No, con props marca error

Comment: LISTO, ya encontré la solución, valide antes de mostrar el formulario

Answer (score 2):

Listo, ya encontré la resuesta, valide antes de mostrar el formulario, Gracias por su atención.

```
{
                selectedUser ?
                <form
                            className="formulario-nuevo-proyecto"
                            onSubmit={onSubmit}
                        >
                            <input 
                                type="number"
                                className="input-text"
                                name="idUnidad"
                                value={selectedUser.idTipoTabla}
                                onChange={handleChange}
                            />
                            <input 
                                type="number"
                                className="input-text"
                                name="idTipoTabla"
                                value={selectedUser.idUnidad}
                                onChange={handleChange}
                            />                                                        
                            <input 
                                type="text"
                                className="input-text"
                                placeholder="Nombre Tarea..."
                                name="titulo"
                                value={selectedUser.titulo}
                                onChange={handleChange}
                            />
                            <label value="Descripcion"></label>
                            <input 
                                type="text"
                                className="input-text"
                                placeholder="Descripción"
                                name="descripcion"
                                value={selectedUser.descripcion}
                                onChange={handleChange}
                            />                            

                            <input 
                                type="submit"
                                className="btn btn-primary btn-block"
                                value="Editar Proyecto"
                            />

                        </form>
                :
                null
            }
```

Comment: No olvides marcarla como aceptada por favor